# Possible Outputs of Semaphore Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, operating-system, semaphore

I'm trying to wrap my head around semaphores and how they work but to no avail.  I have a question on an assignment that says

Consider the semaphore algorithm shown below.

```
semaphore S <- 1, T <- 0
p                       q
p1: wait (S)         q1: wait (T)
p2: write (“p”)      q2: write (“q”)
p3: signal (T)       q3: signal (S)

a.  What are the possible outputs for this algorithm?
```

Can someone lead me in the right direction to figure out how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
>    sem_wait()  decrements (locks) the semaphore pointed to by sem.  If the semaphore's value
>    is greater than zero, then the decrement proceeds, and the function returns, immediately.
>    If  the  semaphore  currently  has  the  value zero, then the call blocks until either it
>    becomes possible to perform the decrement (i.e., the semaphore value rises  above  zero),
>    or a signal handler interrupts the call.
> ```

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_wait.3.html

If semaphore includes value greater than one the process calling wait can continue without blocking. When wait call returns semaphore value has been decrement by one limiting number of process/threads that can enter semaphore protected code block.

The initial state in your code make only possible output "pq" because thread p continues without blocking in first wait call. While thread q blocks in first wait until thread p calls signal(T). The call to signal increments the semaphore. If at time of signal call semaphore has value 0 and there is blocking thread(s) waiting it one of threads returns to running state.

WARNING: It is bad idea to call wait and signal for different semaphores in begin and end of a block. It is easy to end up with complex state multithreaded state transitions that cause race conditions or deadlocks. After saying that I have to admit to using semaphores in unit test in very similar manner to control operation ordering for two ipc processes.

Comment: Since the value decrements wouldn't the output be "ppq" since it will with p first, then S will be set to 0, run p again then unblock q and q can run?

Comment: I understood there was no loops in pseudocode. If you mean that both p and q are running while(true) forever loop then you get always "pqpqpq...". That is because p thread will block in second call to wait(S) until thread q calls signal(S) after writing "q".